# SSIS - How to insert all values inside ""

Tags: ssis

there is a requirement for all the values integrating from SQL Server into a flat file (.csv) being inserted between a double quotation mark, such as 123 to be inserted as "123".
I am having such difficulty with this, i tried the derived columns with the script `"\"\"" + [columnName] + "\"\""` but does not work at all.
Please be advised i need the column headers to have the same "" as well.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to export data from SQL Server into a csv file using SSIS, and that you want the values to be double quoted, you just need to set the `Text Qualifier` property of your Destination connection to a double quote `"` character.

Comment: @P.MAJ  *"does not work at all"* - Given this is the proper way to quote your outputs, you will need to be more specific here.  Please add *details* on what you have tried and the issues you face when doing so to your question.  E.g. add the error you see or a representation of your output when trying to set a `Text Qualifier`

Comment: so i have tried to put " in the Text qualifier field. the first column will have its header just as normal. then the values will be like 123"" and the other columns will have the headers and values as normal like 123. can share an image if you want!?

Comment: actually, if i remove the derived column bit, and just put " in the text qualifier, it does not even add " anywhere to the text. it just shows all the headers and values as plain 123, string values or integers.

Comment: Are you trying to quote wrap non-Text fields.

Comment: @P.MAJ *"can share an image if you want!?"* - Please do, of your source data, connection settings and output if possible.

Comment: before i do that, just wanted to clarify this; when i use the " in text qualifier, if i open the created file with notepad, it has " such as "abc" and "123"for all vlaues, but when i open it with Excel it shows the values as abc and 123. does this mean that everything works and there is a problem with Excel? in that case you have already answered and i was trying to look at the csv file incorrectly.

Comment: @P.MAJ Yes, Excel has a habit of trying to be 'helpful' and causing all sorts of issues.  You should avoid using Excel with CSV files as much as possible for this reason.